# Mutual Python Subclasses (issubclass returns True both ways around)

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

So my understanding is that Python disallows mutual subclassing (A being a subclass of B, while B is also a subclass of A), which is sensible as the concept doesn't make much sense.

That said, I seem to have that exact situation and I have no idea why that's the case.

You can reproduce the issue with something as simple as this:

```
import os
from abc import ABC

class Path(os.PathLike, ABC):
    pass

class File(Path):
    def __fspath__(self):
        pass

class Dir(Path):
    def __fspath__(self):
        pass


issubclass(File, Dir)
issubclass(Dir, File)

isinstance(File(), Dir)
isinstance(Dir(), File)
```

Both of those calls to issubclass() return True. Same thing for the calls to isinstance().

I've subclassed the File and Dir classes from the Path class, and I've subclassed the Path class from the os.PathLike abstract base class. File and Dir should both be subclasses of Path, and not subclasses of each other.

I've further tried looking at the method resolution order to try to see if something in the class hierarchy is screwed up, but it looks normal:

```
import inspect

inspect.getmro(File)
inspect.getmro(Dir)
```

output:

```
(__main__.File, __main__.Path, os.PathLike, abc.ABC, object)
(__main__.Dir, __main__.Path, os.PathLike, abc.ABC, object)
```

Could someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Please edit your post with the actual code - copy-pasted, and including your class definitions.

Comment: I've updated the post with actual code now @brunodesthuilliers. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.PathLike` implements the datamodel [`__subclasshook__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__):

```
class PathLike(abc.ABC):

    """Abstract base class for implementing the file system path protocol."""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __fspath__(self):
        """Return the file system path representation of the object."""
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, subclass):
        return hasattr(subclass, '__fspath__')
```

It means *any* class implementing `__fspath__` will be considered a subclass.

```
>>> class Other: 
...     __fspath__ = None 
... 
>>> issubclass(Other, Path)
True
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch, I'd never heard of \_\_subclasshook__ before. Is there any way to bypass this bevaviour and still use isinstance() to check for File-ness (but not Dir-ness). For example, treating an instance of File (or an instance of a subclass of File) as a File, but not an instance of Dir.

Comment: I would say, just don't use the abstract base classes. A lot of the time, these seem just like unnecessary complication in Python.